# Extract images from PDF file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf

I want to write JavaScript code to extract all image files from a PDF file, perhaps getting them as JPG or some other image format. There is already some JavaScript code for reading a PDF file, for example in the PDF viewer [pdf-js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/viewer.js).

```
window.addEventListener('change', function webViewerChange(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files;
  if (!files || files.length === 0)
    return;

  // Read the local file into a Uint8Array.
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function webViewerChangeFileReaderOnload(evt) {
    var buffer = evt.target.result;
    var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    PDFView.open(uint8Array, 0);
  };

  var file = files[0];
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  PDFView.setTitleUsingUrl(file.name);
  ........
```

Can this code be used to extract images from a PDF file?

Comment: this should work. But the right code is now here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/gh-pages/build/pdf.js#L1112 `function loadJpegStream`

Answer (score 26):

If you open a page with `pdf.js`, for example

```
PDFJS.getDocument({url: <pdf file>}).then(function (doc) {
    doc.getPage(1).then(function (page) {
        window.page = page;
    })
})
```

you can then use `getOperatorList` to search for `paintJpegXObject` objects and grab the resources.

```
window.objs = []
page.getOperatorList().then(function (ops) {
    for (var i=0; i < ops.fnArray.length; i++) {
        if (ops.fnArray[i] == PDFJS.OPS.paintJpegXObject) {
            window.objs.push(ops.argsArray[i][0])
        }
    }
})
```

Now `args` will have a list of the resources from that page that you need to fetch.

```
console.log(window.args.map(function (a) { page.objs.get(a) }))
```

should print to the console a bunch of `<img />` objects with data-uri `src=` attributes.  These can be directly inserted into the page, or you can do more scripting to get at the raw data.

It only works for embedded JPEG objects, but it's a start!

Comment: Typos. Change to `i < ops.fnArray.length` and `PDFJS.OPS.paintJpegXObject`

Comment: @JasonSiefken after extract an image file and do some operation on it, like resizing image, How can I insert it back to file for replace the existing image inside file? Thanks

Comment: If you call `page.objs.get()` before the image is loaded, you get an error. To be safe, pass a callback as the second parameter to `get()` instead of relying on a return value. Working example: https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/MxwGQZ

Comment: Together with paintJpegXObject comparison, you can also check for paintImageXObject. This worked in my case, probably because a pdf contained png objects.

Comment: Like this: if(ops.fnArray[i] == PDFJS.OPS.paintJpegXObject || ops.fnArray[i] == PDFJS.OPS.paintImageXObject) {

Comment: What about the `paintImageXObject` .png and other types, it's giving `Uint8ClampedArray ` now converting Uint8ClampedArray array to image is new challange :)

Comment: This could be a great npm package, if someone lacks a nice project and have the skills 

Answer (score 1):

Here is [link](https://giters.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/13709) to working example of getting images from pdf and adding alpha channel to Uint8ClampedArray to be able to display it. It displays images in canvas.

Example in codepen: https://codepen.io/allandiego/pen/RwVGbyj

Getting data url from canvas to be able to display it in img tag:

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = imageWidth;
canvas.height = imageHeight;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx!.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: this doesn't extract, but only convert a canvas to an image.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this and doesn't want to implement the various cases him/herself, I finally found a library that does everything for me - **pdf-img-convert**. It uses pdf.js under the hood.

```
npm install pdf-img-convert
```

And use like this:

```
import { convert } from "pdf-img-convert";

const outputImages = await convert("/path/to/pdf.pdf");
const imagePaths = outputImages.map((image, i) => {
  const path = "output" + i + ".png";
  writeFileSync(path, image);
  return path;
});
```