# JavaScript - Read all content of pdf using pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I am using [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) to read the text inside  `pdf` file, it works fine like - [code example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/x2rajt5g/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=x2rajt5g), but I want to extract `images` that the file contains as well.
I didn't found any part in `pdf.js` that can extract both text and image.

Thanks.

Comment: I do not know of a tool for doing this without actually evaluating the operators.  You may have to look at the PartialEvaluator_getOperatorList and then parse/pull out the image objects.

Comment: There is another question on this, but I am not sure how helpful it would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680261/extract-images-from-pdf-file-with-javascript

Comment: Thank, I will try this.

Comment: SVG viewer example at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/svgviewer ?