# Extract images from a single PDF page using PDFJS

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

Is there a way to extract images from a single PDF page using PDFJS framework?
After some googling, I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.pdf-js/G8JcAgMRVRI) discussion talking about that, but unfortunately its not very specific, he talks about passing an **imageLayer** to the **CanvasGraphics** object, but I didn't recognize what he does mean by that.

Comment: does the answer here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680261/extract-images-from-pdf-file-with-javascript

Comment: Yes I tried it, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

```
 let imgIndex = 1;
   let opList = await page.getOperatorList();
            for (let k = 0; k < opList.fnArray.length; k++) {
                if (opList.fnArray[k] == pdfjsLib.OPS.paintJpegXObject || opList.fnArray[k] == pdfjsLib.OPS.paintImageXObject) {

                    function getImage() {
                        return new Promise(async function (res, rej) {
                            let img = null
                            try {
   //-------either get data from page.objs.get
                                img = page.objs.get(opList.argsArray[k][0])

                            } catch (err) {
                                if (opList.argsArray[k][0].startsWith("g_")) {
   //---------or get data from page.commonObjs.get
                                    img = page.commonObjs.get(opList.argsArray[k][0])
                                } else {
                                    res()
                                }
                            }
                            try {
//------------------ directly creating image data from returned array does not print proper image also sometimes throw error.
                            // var idata = new ImageData(img.data, img.width);
                                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                                canvas.width = img.width;
                                canvas.height = img.height;
                                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//------------------- below function will process data and print proper image on provided canvas context. kind parameter in returned data is used in this function to prcess the data
                                putBinaryImageData(ctx, img)
                                // ctx.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);

                                function getCanvasBlob(canvas) {
                                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                                        canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                                            resolve(blob)
                                        })
                                    })
                                }
                                getCanvasBlob(canvas).then((blob) => {
                                    zip.folder('images').file(`page-${i}-image-${imgIndex}`, blob, { base64: false });
                                    imgIndex++;
                                    res()
                                }).catch((err) => {
                                    // console.log(err)
                                    res()
                                })
                            } catch (err) {
                                console.log(err)
                                res()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    await getImage()
                }
            }
```

IMP ----------- Below function is taken from source code of PDF.js to convert  image data to proper images as the data returned from pdf.js inbuilt function for images is uint8clampedarray which can not be used as it is for images, this data needs to be processed which is being done using below function.

```
export function putBinaryImageData(ctx, imgData, transferMaps = null) {
 
    const FULL_CHUNK_HEIGHT = 16;

    const ImageKind = {
        GRAYSCALE_1BPP: 1,
        RGB_24BPP: 2,
        RGBA_32BPP: 3
      };

    if (typeof ImageData !== "undefined" && imgData instanceof ImageData) {
      ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
      return;
    }

    const height = imgData.height,
          width = imgData.width;
    const partialChunkHeight = height % FULL_CHUNK_HEIGHT;
    const fullChunks = (height - partialChunkHeight) / FULL_CHUNK_HEIGHT;
    const totalChunks = partialChunkHeight === 0 ? fullChunks : fullChunks + 1;
    const chunkImgData = ctx.createImageData(width, FULL_CHUNK_HEIGHT);
    let srcPos = 0,
        destPos;
    const src = imgData.data;
    const dest = chunkImgData.data;
    let i, j, thisChunkHeight, elemsInThisChunk;
    let transferMapRed, transferMapGreen, transferMapBlue, transferMapGray;

    if (transferMaps) {
      switch (transferMaps.length) {
        case 1:
          transferMapRed = transferMaps[0];
          transferMapGreen = transferMaps[0];
          transferMapBlue = transferMaps[0];
          transferMapGray = transferMaps[0];
          break;

        case 4:
          transferMapRed = transferMaps[0];
          transferMapGreen = transferMaps[1];
          transferMapBlue = transferMaps[2];
          transferMapGray = transferMaps[3];
          break;
      }
    }

    if (imgData.kind === ImageKind.GRAYSCALE_1BPP) {
      const srcLength = src.byteLength;
      const dest32 = new Uint32Array(dest.buffer, 0, dest.byteLength >> 2);
      const dest32DataLength = dest32.length;
      const fullSrcDiff = width + 7 >> 3;
      let white = 0xffffffff;
      let black = _util.IsLittleEndianCached.value ? 0xff000000 : 0x000000ff;

      if (transferMapGray) {
        if (transferMapGray[0] === 0xff && transferMapGray[0xff] === 0) {
          [white, black] = [black, white];
        }
      }

      for (i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++) {
        thisChunkHeight = i < fullChunks ? FULL_CHUNK_HEIGHT : partialChunkHeight;
        destPos = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < thisChunkHeight; j++) {
          const srcDiff = srcLength - srcPos;
          let k = 0;
          const kEnd = srcDiff > fullSrcDiff ? width : srcDiff * 8 - 7;
          const kEndUnrolled = kEnd & ~7;
          let mask = 0;
          let srcByte = 0;

          for (; k < kEndUnrolled; k += 8) {
            srcByte = src[srcPos++];
            dest32[destPos++] = srcByte & 128 ? white : black;
            dest32[destPos++] = srcByte & 64 ? white : black;
            dest32[destPos++] = srcByte & 32 ? white : black;
            dest32[destPos++] = srcByte & 16 ? white : black;
            dest32[destPos++] = srcByte & 8 ? white : black;
            dest32[destPos++] = srcByte & 4 ? white : black;
            dest32[destPos++] = srcByte & 2 ? white : black;
            dest32[destPos++] = srcByte & 1 ? white : black;
          }

          for (; k < kEnd; k++) {
            if (mask === 0) {
              srcByte = src[srcPos++];
              mask = 128;
            }

            dest32[destPos++] = srcByte & mask ? white : black;
            mask >>= 1;
          }
        }

        while (destPos < dest32DataLength) {
          dest32[destPos++] = 0;
        }

        ctx.putImageData(chunkImgData, 0, i * FULL_CHUNK_HEIGHT);
      }
    } else if (imgData.kind === ImageKind.RGBA_32BPP) {
      const hasTransferMaps = !!(transferMapRed || transferMapGreen || transferMapBlue);
      j = 0;
      elemsInThisChunk = width * FULL_CHUNK_HEIGHT * 4;

      for (i = 0; i < fullChunks; i++) {
        dest.set(src.subarray(srcPos, srcPos + elemsInThisChunk));
        srcPos += elemsInThisChunk;

        if (hasTransferMaps) {
          for (let k = 0; k < elemsInThisChunk; k += 4) {
            if (transferMapRed) {
              dest[k + 0] = transferMapRed[dest[k + 0]];
            }

            if (transferMapGreen) {
              dest[k + 1] = transferMapGreen[dest[k + 1]];
            }

            if (transferMapBlue) {
              dest[k + 2] = transferMapBlue[dest[k + 2]];
            }
          }
        }

        ctx.putImageData(chunkImgData, 0, j);
        j += FULL_CHUNK_HEIGHT;
      }

      if (i < totalChunks) {
        elemsInThisChunk = width * partialChunkHeight * 4;
        dest.set(src.subarray(srcPos, srcPos + elemsInThisChunk));

        if (hasTransferMaps) {
          for (let k = 0; k < elemsInThisChunk; k += 4) {
            if (transferMapRed) {
              dest[k + 0] = transferMapRed[dest[k + 0]];
            }

            if (transferMapGreen) {
              dest[k + 1] = transferMapGreen[dest[k + 1]];
            }

            if (transferMapBlue) {
              dest[k + 2] = transferMapBlue[dest[k + 2]];
            }
          }
        }

        ctx.putImageData(chunkImgData, 0, j);
      }
    } else if (imgData.kind === ImageKind.RGB_24BPP) {
      const hasTransferMaps = !!(transferMapRed || transferMapGreen || transferMapBlue);
      thisChunkHeight = FULL_CHUNK_HEIGHT;
      elemsInThisChunk = width * thisChunkHeight;

      for (i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++) {
        if (i >= fullChunks) {
          thisChunkHeight = partialChunkHeight;
          elemsInThisChunk = width * thisChunkHeight;
        }

        destPos = 0;

        for (j = elemsInThisChunk; j--;) {
          dest[destPos++] = src[srcPos++];
          dest[destPos++] = src[srcPos++];
          dest[destPos++] = src[srcPos++];
          dest[destPos++] = 255;
        }

        if (hasTransferMaps) {
          for (let k = 0; k < destPos; k += 4) {
            if (transferMapRed) {
              dest[k + 0] = transferMapRed[dest[k + 0]];
            }

            if (transferMapGreen) {
              dest[k + 1] = transferMapGreen[dest[k + 1]];
            }

            if (transferMapBlue) {
              dest[k + 2] = transferMapBlue[dest[k + 2]];
            }
          }
        }

        ctx.putImageData(chunkImgData, 0, i * FULL_CHUNK_HEIGHT);
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error(`bad image kind: ${imgData.kind}`);
    }
  }
```